# Why ruby cannot run the .rb files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner just starting to learn ruby. The tutorials I have been reading say that I can create a file with the extension `.rb`(eg. hello.rb) and run the file in the command prompt by typing ruby hello.rb. But when I create and save the file on the desktop and run it in the cmd it always gives me this error message:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ruby hello.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby: No such file or directory -- hello.rb (LoadError)
```

I searched the internet and read a lot of other tutorials but none of them seem to have any discussion on this issue.

Can someone give me any hints on this please?
Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to `cd` (change directory) to the directory containing hello.rb first... or pass the entire path of the file to ruby...

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the correct path to your file, since it's not located in `system32` directory, this relative path won't work. If it's on the desktop, it would be something like this, probably:

```
ruby %HOMEPATH%\Desktop\hello.rb
```

or you can change your current directory to desktop before you start playing with ruby:

```
cd %HOMEPATH%\Desktop
```

from now on, you can easily use relative path, since `hello.rb` is located in the same directory you're in currently in your command line:

```
ruby hello.rb
```

I'm not quite sure of exact syntax etc, I don't use Windows cmd very often - you would have to experiment on your own.

There may be context menu option like "open command line here" in Windows, but I'm not sure of it as well.

Also, you may need to learn basics of command line even before you start to learn Ruby.

Comment: sorry I know this sounds stupid but I just wanna ask how to cd into the correct directory and what is the correct directory?

Comment: 'correct directory' in this context it's the directory where you have your `hello.rb` file located, so it's probably your Desktop (it's a directory as well). I wrote how to do it (well, most probably) in my answer.

I strongly advice learning some command-line basics first.

Comment: The "open command line here" can be accessed through Shift + right click, which should provide the option "open PowerShell here" when in explorer.